# Problems with ActualWidth not being recalculated

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridcolumn, actualwidth

How come is the `ActualWidth` of a `DataGridColumn` is not affected by changing the value of its `Width` property but it is when I change the value of its `MinWidth`?  In other words how does `ActualWidth` get computed or changed ?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a difference between using:

```
double width = 25.0;
myDataGridColumn.Width = width;
```

and:

```
double width = 25.0;
myDataGridColumn.Width = new DataGridLength(width, DataGridLengthUnitType.Pixel);
```

The latest activates the recomputing of `ActualWidth` but not the first one.

Don't know why.